# Compute pct_change upto NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, percentage

I have a df with index extending past the last data point:

df

```
2022-01-31  96.210  21649.6
2022-02-28  96.390  21708.4
2022-03-31  97.410  21739.7
2022-04-30  98.630  21644.3
2022-05-31  103.744 21649.2
2022-06-30  102.498 21607.4
2022-07-31  105.138 21636.1
2022-08-31  105.450 21631.8
2022-09-30  109.691 21503.1
2022-10-31  111.745 21414.8
2022-11-30  111.481 21351.6
2022-12-31  104.728 NaN
2023-01-31  103.522 NaN
2023-02-28  NaN
2023-03-31  NaN
2023-04-30  NaN
2023-05-31  NaN
2023-06-30  NaN 
2023-07-31  NaN 
2023-08-31  NaN
```

and when I compute pct_change, pandas treats NaNs as values and extends the pct_change calculation past the last actual data point. So instead stopping on 2023-01-31 for the first column, pandas continues computing values for 2023-02-28 and so on:

df.pct_change(12)

```
2022-01-31  0.069713    0.117543
2022-02-28  0.059464    0.106713
2022-03-31  0.069969    0.094989
2022-04-30  0.061336    0.076258
2022-05-31  0.140671    0.060263
2022-06-30  0.141022    0.056075
2022-07-31  0.135400    0.049517
2022-08-31  0.145573    0.038228
2022-09-30  0.186490    0.025632
2022-10-31  0.188271    0.012812
2022-11-30  0.187484    0.000112
2022-12-31  0.090576    -0.006440
2023-01-31  0.076000    -0.013765
2023-02-28  0.073991    -0.016436
2023-03-31  0.062745    -0.017852
2023-04-30  0.049600    -0.013523
2023-05-31  -0.002140   -0.013746
2023-06-30  0.009990    -0.011839
2023-07-31  -0.015370   -0.013149
2023-08-31  -0.018284   -0.012953
```

How can I tell pandas to compute pct_change only upto NaN values? So the output is:

```
2022-01-31  0.069713    0.117543
2022-02-28  0.059464    0.106713
2022-03-31  0.069969    0.094989
2022-04-30  0.061336    0.076258
2022-05-31  0.140671    0.060263
2022-06-30  0.141022    0.056075
2022-07-31  0.135400    0.049517
2022-08-31  0.145573    0.038228
2022-09-30  0.186490    0.025632
2022-10-31  0.188271    0.012812
2022-11-30  0.187484    0.000112
2022-12-31  0.090576    NaN
2023-01-31  0.076000    NaN
2023-02-28  NaN         NaN
2023-03-31  NaN         NaN
2023-04-30  NaN         NaN
2023-05-31  NaN         NaN
2023-06-30  NaN         NaN
2023-07-31  NaN         NaN
2023-08-31  NaN         NaN
```

The following options won't work for me:

1. dropna
2. specifying a range a-la `df=df[:'2023-01-31'].pct_change(12)`

I need to keep the index past the last data point and I am doing a lot of different pct_changes so specifying a range everytime is too time consuming, I am looking for a nicer solution.

Also, specifying a range won't work because when when the df gets new data points, I will have to manually adjust all of the ranges, which is no bueno.

Comment: what exactly is the **explicit** expected output? Also, you should get NaN in the initial periods

Comment: Just take your result and do `df_output.mask(df.isna())`.

Comment: How do you compute `0.069713`?

Comment: I have data all the way from 1970s

Comment: OK then please provide a reproducible example next time, this will save everyone's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [`df.pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html), you'll find that it has a parameter `fill_method` that uses `pad` as the default for handling NaN values *before* computing the changes. `pad` (or `ffill`) means that the function is propagating the last valid observation forward. E.g. in your first column, with `periods=12`, when you reach the index value `2023-02-28`, instead of using the NaN value, the function picks the last valid value (`103.522` at `2023-01-31`) to do the calculation:

```
103.522/96.390-1

# 0.0739910779126467 (96.390 being the value at `2022-02-28`, one year earlier)
```

To avoid this, you want to set `fill_method` to `bfill` (cf. the documentation for [`df.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) for these methods). Result examplified below with `periods=3` (I trust you are only showing  the last rows of a longer `df`, because otherwise all the values before `2023-01-31` should be NaN values):

```
df.pct_change(periods=3, fill_method='bfill')

                col1      col2
2022-01-31       NaN       NaN
2022-02-28       NaN       NaN
2022-03-31       NaN       NaN
2022-04-30  0.025153 -0.000245
2022-05-31  0.076294 -0.002727
2022-06-30  0.052233 -0.006086
2022-07-31  0.065984 -0.000379
2022-08-31  0.016444 -0.000804
2022-09-30  0.070177 -0.004827
2022-10-31  0.062841 -0.010228
2022-11-30  0.057193 -0.012953
2022-12-31 -0.045245       NaN
2023-01-31 -0.073587       NaN
2023-02-28       NaN       NaN
2023-03-31       NaN       NaN
2023-04-30       NaN       NaN
2023-05-31       NaN       NaN
2023-06-30       NaN       NaN
2023-07-31       NaN       NaN
2023-08-31       NaN       NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put `ptc_change(limit=1)`, which will stop comparison further after 1 null comparison.

Comment: With `limit=1`, the function will still calculate a percentage change for `2023-02-28` in the first column (`0.073991`), but the OP wants the calculation to stop 1 row earlier, at the last valid observation.